# DIV MOVEMENT ERROR

Tags: html, dynamic, positioning

i have this problem.
i have this pink div at the bottom of my page

http://www.manadg.com.ar/1.png

i want the div to stay always at the bottom.
even when i resize, or when i scroll down to see the content of the page

when i resize the div moves with the bottom of the web browser´s window

but when i scroll down everything is messed up. the div is static, it stays in the same place it appears when i first enter the html.
like this

http://www.manadg.com.ar/3.png

here is my code

if anyone is able to help me, i would appreciate it.
thanks

```
#divbar 
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#f06;
margin-left:-20px;
color:#fff;
}
```

and then just have the id tag with id=divbar

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you meant, you wanted a footer that stays on the bottom of the PAGE as well as the Browser window..

try this:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Or try changing position to: 
position:fixed;

Maybe that's what you meant..

Comment: Thank you very much! just changing the position to fixed did the job! ive been fighting with this div the whole day. thank you. i appreciate your help! cheers!